# Printing output on new lines in ansible jinja2 template

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am struggling with this script to print it's output on new lines. I have tried a few proposed solutions online but none seem to be working. Below is snippet of my playbook.

```
tasks:
 - debug: msg={% for oct in range(10,12) %}172.16.0.{{ oct }}{% endfor %}
```

The output i am getting is this

```
  TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
     ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "172.16.0.10172.16.0.11"
```

I need an output like this

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
     ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "172.16.0.10"
           "172.16.0.11"
```

I tried insert a `\n` like so `{% for oct in range(10,12) %}172.16.0.{{ oct }}'\n'{% endfor %}` but that only prints the `\n` as a string in my output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve exactly what you want with standard output plugin.

The closest thing is when you print (`debug`) a list – Ansible will print every item on new line:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ lookup('sequence','start=10 end=11 format=172.16.0.%d',wantlist=true) }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "172.16.0.10",
        "172.16.0.11"
    ]
}
```